# Laravel: best way to get locale time in my language in whole admin section?

Tags: laravel, localization

I'm new to Laravel 5 (and to OOP in general) and I'm trying to switch from my old procedural code. In the whole admin section, I need to set the locale time to Italian for viewing purposes (i.e. show dates like "martedì 8 dicembre 2015" instead of "Tuesday 8 December 2015").

So far, I set `'locale' => 'it'` in config/app.php and changed the `routes.php` file like this:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin'], function(){
    setlocale(LC_TIME, config('app.locale'));
    // here go all my routes
});
```

It works, but is this a correct approach (I mean, set a config in routes file)? Is there some more elegant way to keep routes separated from custom configs? Or is it better to keep simplicity like this?

More, I still don't know if this can affect the way dates are stored into database (at the moment I deal only with list of records, not with store or updates) - of course my dates should be stored as ISO

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget that you canalso set this in your App/config/app.php file:

/*

```
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Application Timezone
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify the default timezone for your application, which
    | will be used by the PHP date and date-time functions. We have gone
    | ahead and set this to a sensible default for you out of the box.
    |
    */

    'timezone' => 'Europe/Amsterdam',
```

Comment: How does this affects my problem?