# Laravel: best way to repeatly format a date in my language (italian)

Tags: date, laravel, localization

I am new to Laravel and OOP in general, trying to switch from old procedural code. I'd like to show some dates coming from my Models in my language (italian) for readability reasons: so far, that's what I did:

1. change `'locale' => 'it'` in `config/app.php` file
2. put `setlocale(LC_TIME, config('app.locale'));` in routes.php file, see also my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34162791/laravel-best-way-to-get-locale-time-in-my-language-in-whole-admin-section)
3. put `protected $dates = ['published_at', 'expires_at'];` in my Model(s) to leverage Carbon
4. put `{{ utf8_encode($record->published_at->formatLocalized('%A %d %B %Y')) }}` in my Blade view(s)

(NOTE: I MUST use `utf8_encode()`, otherwise dates with accented letters (lunedì, martedì, etc.) don't show up: don't know why and can't find the answer googling... is there a reason for this? Is it a Laravel or Carbon bug?)

My question is about the last point: writing that long

```
{{ utf8_encode($record->published_at->formatLocalized('%A %d %B %Y')) }}
```

piece of code every time is tedious and it would be faster (and reusable) to write

```
{{ formatItalian($record->published_at) }}
```

(Note that I need it on multiple Models, so I guess I have to avoid Accessors for a more general approach)

What's the best way to accomplish this? I read about the custom helpers functions, would this be a good approach? As I said, I'm new to Laravel switching from procedural code, and trying to use the best practices, so sorry for the dumb question...

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

While you should (and I strongly encourage you to do) open up a bug to fix this in carbon you can easily extend the class and use that
As an example

```
use Carbon\Carbon;
class MyCarbon extends Carbon
{
    public function formatItalian($format)
    {
        return utf8_encode($this->formatLocalized($format))
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that this is not tested and was written just to give you a hint.

Comment: Thanks, I opened a bug but, since it seems I am the only one having the problem, they said it depends from my configuration (I'm using IIS instead of Apache) but they can't say where...